# Probability of two identical weekly lottery draws in one year.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

In a particular country a weekly lottery is held by selecting 4 numbers (randomly without return and without importance of order) of the numbers 1 to 12. What is the probability that during a year (which has 52 weeks, which means 52 lottery games) will the two lottery come out the same?


This is the way I have solved the question:
The event to choose 4 numbers from 12 is $\binom{12}{4}$
The sample space is $\binom{12}{4}^{52}$.
The event to choose 2 similar lotteries is $\binom{52}{2}$.
So the probability is: $\frac{\binom{52}{2}}{\binom{12}{4}^{52}}$.

Is my answer correct? Because I fill that the probability is too much small.

Comment: Also consult the Wikipedia plot summary on the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for more on this general class of problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are two mistakes, a big one and a small one.

The big one is that you've only counted the number $\binom{52}2$ of ways to choose the two matching weeks, but not the number $\binom{12}4$ of matching results that could occur in these weeks.

The smaller mistake is that you didn't take into account that there could be more than two matching lotteries, and you'd be overcounting those cases.

To avoid the second mistake, you can calculate the number of ways that no weeks match: You can choose one of $\binom{12}4=495$ lotteries for the first week, one of the remaining $494$ for the second, etc. Thus the probability for all results to be different is

$$
\frac{495!}{(495-52)!495^{52}}\approx0.06\;,
$$

and the probability for at least two to be the same is the complement, about $0.94$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and I am very sorry for not responding till know, I was a little bit busy.

Comment: @violettagold: No problem, I know the feeling :-)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I have another question. Now I need to calculate the probability the two lotteries are exactly the same, how can I do this with the help of your result?

Comment: Can I say that this probability is $\frac{1\cdot 1\cdot 493!}{(495-52)!\cdot 495^{^{52}}}$?

Comment: @violettagold: I don't understand -- isn't that the probability that was already calculated? What do you mean by "exactly the same"? Or perhaps you mean the probability that exactly two lotteries are the same?

Comment: yes, the probability that exactly two lotteries are the same

Comment: @violettagold: You can choose two lotteries in $\binom{52}2$ ways. That leaves $51$ results to choose, and the count for that is the one in the answer, with one $52$ replaced by $51$. So in all this is

$$
\binom{52}2\frac{495!}{(495-51)!495^{52}}\approx0.186\;,
$$

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for all your help. This topic is a little bit difficult for me to understand. Thank you for the patience :)